# RestKit installation to XCode gives multiple errors

Tags: ios, restkit

I am using a project without ARC. I am trying to install RestKit on to the project. I tried following instructions given in the following links:
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/README.md
http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial

But I am getting following errors
[image: Errors found after following instructions]

The errors happen on following lines:
1. Unexpected @ in the program:

```
   NSArray *attributeNames = [userInfoValue isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] ? userInfoValue : @[ userInfoValue ];
```

Is this a valid Obj C syntax first of all.

2. Array subscript is not an integer

NSAttributeDescription *attribute = [entity attributesByName][attributeName];

attributeName is a CFStringRef

Has any one faced these issues. Please inform me the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is do to the use of Objective-C literal subscript access to the attribute property.

What version of Xcode are you building against and with what base SDK? Under Xcode 4.5.2 with a base SDK of 6.0 it compiles without an issue.

Comment: I upgraded and it started working. I got "Restkit/Restkit.h" not found error. However I did as following as given in another stack overflow post. "Solution I found was not to copy and past the "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../Headers" to your target's Header Search Paths.

After five hours I deleted the copy and pasted " and manually typed them in and it worked."